# Is possible react-navigation-drawer with subpages?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, side-menu

i'm using react-native with  react-navigation-drawer to generate a side menu for navigate beetwen screens.
My question is: Exist a way or a guide to put subpages in the side menu?
any suggestion is welcome and thank you in advance
On left how appear  my menu and on right is what i want:

[image: myscreens]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can customized it using

> CustomDrawerContent

it has alot of option please do read about it not all of item needs to be customized
i just made this example fast for you

documentaion

> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#providing-a-custom-drawercontent

```
  import  React from 'react';
import { View, Text,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

function Feed() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Feed Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function Article() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Article Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function CustomDrawerContent({ navigation ,progress, ...rest }) {
  const translateX = Animated.interpolate(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [-100, 0],
  });
const [isshow,show] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...rest}>
      <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateX }] }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{show(true)}}>
      <Text>
      press me
      </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
      {isshow ? (

        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('Feed')}}>
        <Text> page one 1</Text>
</TouchableOpacity> 
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('Article')}}>
        <Text> page one 2</Text>
</TouchableOpacity> 
</View>

      ):null}
      </View>
      </Animated.View>
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Article" component={Article} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyDrawer />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

expo link

> https://snack.expo.io/cXuBvzs87